# Gigabyte GV-N680OC-4GD causes Gigabyte GA-X79-UD3 not to boot

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard

Building a new system, the mother board is the [Gigabyte GA-X79-UD3](http://www.gigabyte.com.au/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4050#ov) with F7+ Bios version.

The Graphics card is the [Gigabyte GV-N680OC-4GD](http://www.gigabyte.com.au/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4373#ov).

At power on, the system hangs on the BIOS splash screen, it is non-responsive to keyboard input. after a minute or to, a blank screen with a flashing underscore is displayed. The underscore flashes quite fast.

If no boot media is present, it will eventually display the "no boot media" message, though the B's are missing, so it reads something like "no oot media".

I replaced the Gigabyte GV-N680OC-4GD with the Gigabyte GV-N670OC-2GD and it booted perfectly. Also tried a Gigabyte Radeon HD 4000 series Card and it again booted perfectly.

This is where it get's annoying, I put the Gigabyte GV-N680OC-4GD into an ASRock mother board (where the Gigabyte GV-N670OC-2GD came from) and it worked fine.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

The Gigabyte GA-X79-UD3 supports PCIe 3.0.

Here is a list of things I've tried, most of which is redundant since the mother board boots with diffident Graphics cards:

- swapped out known good RAM
- removed BIOS battery over night
- removed SATA drives
- removed all accsesorys (audio, usb, etc..)
- moved the Gigabyte GV-N680OC-4GD to all PCIe slots

Here is the full system list:

- Gigabyte GV-N680OC-4GD
- GIGABYTE GA-X79-UD3
- Intel Core i7 3930K
- G.Skill - F3-19200CL10Q-32GBZHD (4x8GB) 2400Mhz DDR3
- Antec 750W High Current Gamer Power Supply
- Intel 240GB SSD, 520 Series

My only theory is that it is under-powered, possible? I don't have a higher powered PSU to check though.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What model ASROCK board?  Many people are complaining of artifacting and boot problems with the GV-N680OC-4GD on PCI-E 3.0 boards, whereas the card works fine on PCI-E 2.0.
Also, There are known issues with [Geforce 600 series cards on the x79 chipset](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/GeForce-600-Series-Kepler-X79-PCIe_3.0,16091.html) due to the incomplete implementation of PCI-E 3.0 on x79.

Your system Bios (F7) is from 2011. Consider updating it to f11 [here.](http://www.gigabyte.com.au/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4050#bios)
This board has "dual bios" so your risk is minimal.

Please also make sure that you have the Bios set to initialize the display from the correct slot under `Init Display First` in the bios:

[image]

- Specifies the first initiation of the monitor display from the installed PCI or PCI Express graphics cards .
- PCIe Slot 1 Sets the graphics card on the PCIEX16_1 slot as the first display. (Default)
- PCIe Slot 2 Sets the graphics card on the PCIEX8_1 slot as the first display.
- PCIe Slot 3 Sets the graphics card on the PCIEX16_2 slot as the first display.
- PCIe Slot 4 Sets the graphics card on the PCIEX8_2 slot as the first display.
- PCI Sets the graphics card on the PCI slot as the first display.

Comment: ahh, PCIe Slot 3 Sets the graphics card on the PCIEX16_2 slot as the first display, that helps. Also I hear there is a PCIe Legacy mode some where, will try both of these and report back!

Answer (score 0):

Having the Bios set to initialize the display from the correct slot under Init Display First in the bios AND setting the PCIe mode to "Legacy" solved the problem.

Thanks to G Koe!

From what I understand, setting the PCIe mode to "Legacy" sets it to PCIe 2.0.
PCIe 3.0 is not fuly utilized by Graphics cards yet so setting the PCIe mode to "Legacy" will not create a bottle-neck.